# /usr/bin/wish：don't have that file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcl

I have a browse.tcl script, when I exec it, the Ubuntu shows :
"bash: ./browse.tcl：/usr/bin/wish：don't have that file or directory"
I tried to find the "wish"
usr/bin$ find wish
find: ‘wish’: don't have that file or directory

How can I get it?

Comment: Off-topic here, but try `aptitude install tk`

Answer (score 2):

It is not part of the default distribution package. In order to install it just do:

```
apt-get install wish
```

Answer (score 1):

WISH is TCL's WIndowsing Shell. On Ubuntu you can install it with `apt-get install wish`.